# What does the power EIRP mean

Tags: rfid

The South Africa regulations states that the maximum power to be transmitted is 4W EIRP. What does this EIRP mean here?

Secondly when using the Friis equation:
Power received(dBm) = Power transmitted + Gain of transmitter - Cable loss - Free space path loss

I have read that the Power EIRP(dBm) = Power transmitted + Gain of transmitter - Cable loss.

Therefore the Friis becomes:
Power received(dBm) = Power EIRP - Free space path loss

And hence the Power EIRP(dBm) is 36.02 dBm (4W EIRP)

Therefore the Friis becomes:
Power received(dBm) = 36.02 - Free space path loss

Is this correct?

Comment: equivalent isotropic radiated power iirc

Comment: Yes but don’t forgot  Fading loss assumptions. If you are not an ideal point to point, with no reflections, this matters.

Comment: its a limitation on Field Strength

Answer (score 1):

1. [EIRP assumes a spherical (isotropic)  antenna used while ERP assumes a half-wave dipole which includes antenna gain in strongest direction but would require more power if it were an isotropic source as defined by IEEE.](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/f36d5d5e2a7f6c643a78e7a480e2a3b2a0b3c587)
2. Yes but also add margin for Fading Losses and BER assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

EIRP means Effective Incident Radiated Power .This figure takes into account the antenna system .If you had a strongly directional antenna with high gain you would not be able to run anything near 4W transmit .On the other had a poor antenna like say a loading coil on a bad ground would allow much more than 4W transmit .

Comment: Actually the reference is not to Incident, rather it is Relative to Isotropic , even though it is an incident wave, incidentally FWIW lol

Comment: By run anything near 4W you mean the power injected into the antenna will basically be really small due to the high gain of the antenna, otherwise you will be exceeding the regulations